# MP3 File Not Playing On Button Select

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

For simplicity, assume this View says alphabet letters in button when you click on said button.

I have been attempting to play the audio files associated with each button, but the files never play. The buttons, individually, are never given outlets, but they are all connected to the function on Touch Up Inside.

```
class UIAlphabetController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate{
   @IBAction func PlaySound(Sender: UIButton) {
      let soundname:String = Sender.currentTitle!
      var player: AVAudioPlayer?

      let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundname, withExtension: "mp3")

      do {
         player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
         guard let player = player else { return }

         player.prepareToPlay()
         player.play()
      } catch let error { print(error.localizedDescription) }
   }
}
```

Since I have had this problem, the `AQDefaultDevice (188): skipping input stream 0 0 0x0` message has been coming up. On testing with breakpoints, both `soundname` and `url` have expected values.

Does anybody have any idea as to how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your instance of AVAudioPlayer outside of the method. If you do this it will keep player around long enough to play the sound. The reason it's not working is because it trashes the player instance after the method is complete because it thinks you are done using it.

```
class UIAlphabetController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
      var player: AVAudioPlayer?
      @IBAction func PlaySound(Sender: UIButton) {
          let soundname:String = Sender.currentTitle!


          let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundname, withExtension: "mp3")

          do {
             player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
             guard let player = player else { return }

             player.prepareToPlay()
             player.play()
          } catch let error { print(error.localizedDescription) }
     }
}
```

Comment: Whelp, that was quick. I didn't realize that that correlated, but that would have saved me a lot of hassle to know. Thanks

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help. @MoMN